# Magento Manage categories page not displaying properly

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have attached the screenshot of the error in the manage categories page. Anyone can help for this error[image]

Comment: Let us know, in which scenario, you got this error?  Please specify the exact magento version too.

Comment: Its 1.9.3.4... My client was doing some seo works. Don't know clearly about why it happened.

Comment: I had same issue I debug all files and found that there were some issue regarding the json encode/decode issue. 
this page is coming in ajax response, and response is in the json format so Try to debug this you will find exact issue.

Comment: Please check the category data. This problem should be due to some html special chars issue or invalid html data, added to the category information.

Answer (score 0):

- Login to admin panel and go to **System > Configuration > Advanced (Developer) > Log Settings**.
- Enable logs creation by changing the value for "**Enabled**" to "**Yes**".
- Click on "**Save Config**" button.
- Now open **Catalog > Manage Categories** section.
- Check **/var/log** folder under document root of Magento. Here you can find some clue under system.log or exception.log files.

You can also check the browser's console for any errors related to javascript.